# Would be vs would have been

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

In the following sentence which is the correct usage? Would have been or would be? Would have been sounds better to me but I am not sure.

"I have written in such a way that there are some words and sentences that would have been/be omitted in a proper (book) review."

Comment: It depends. They **would be omitted** if your script is reviewed. They **would have been omitted** if your script had been reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

"Would have been" presents a scenario that might have occurred but didn't, it is a construction [this page](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-could-have-should-have-would-have/3391128.html) calls a "modal of lost opportunity".